# Need to incorporate Timezone Selection (UTC) within Web App

Tags: javascript, jquery, oracle

I need to incorporate a Timezone dropdown selection within my web app, which I need to use within an Oracle database.

I basically require the user to select their timezone and I then need to use this against time stamp info stored within the Oracle tables.

Unsure where/how to build this Timezone selection list within my page - example how-tos would be great.

Would like this to be UTC.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could build this from the V$TIMEZONE_NAMES view - it's granted to PUBLIC in a typical installation.